# How extract dictionary keys and set them as column headers in a Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

This question is an offshoot of [How to remove curly braces, apostrophes and square brackets from dictionaries in a Pandas dataframe (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39928273/how-to-remove-curly-braces-apostrophes-and-square-brackets-from-dictionaries-in).

I have the following data in a **csv file**:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

the_data = """
ABC,2016-6-9 0:00,95,"{'//PurpleCar': [115L], '//YellowCar': [403L]}","{'GBP/NOK PAWS': [151L], 'CAD/EUR': [41L], 'EDM8-EDM9': [1833L]}"   
ABC,2016-6-10 0:00,0,"{'//PurpleCar': [219L], '//YellowCar': [381L]}","{'FBTPM5 2015-06-08': [472L], 'HKD/MXN': [0L], 'AUD/SEK DEWS': [19482L]}"   
ABC,2016-6-11 0:00,0,"{'//PurpleCar': [572L], '//YellowCar': [184L]}","{'V 2.000 03/31/25': [759L], 'AUD/JPY': [742L], 'AUD/SEK PAWS': [1784L]}"   
ABC,2016-6-12 0:00,0,"{'//PurpleCar': [80L], '//YellowCar': [2011L]}","{'CAR/FIN SWAP': [151L], 'HKD/MXN': [41L], 'RU4': [5829L]}"   
ABC,2016-6-13 0:00,0,"{'//PurpleCar': [32L], '//YellowCar': [15L]}","{'TRY/CHY OIS': [673L], 'NZD/MXN': [582L], 'AUD/SEK PAPS': [4846242L]}"   
DEF,2016-6-9 0:00,0,"{'//PurpleCar': [19L], '//BlackCar': [17L]}","{'ULM5-ULU5 2015-06-19': [18L], 'HKD/MXN': [64L], 'USD/JPY OPTS': [14714L]}"   
DEF,2016-6-10 0:00,0,"{'//PurpleCar': [32L], '//BlackCar': [15L]}","{'U 4.500 2/15/14': [151L], 'FVU6-FVZ6 2016-09-30': [194], 'AUD/SEK': [0L]}"   
DEF,2016-6-11 0:00,0,"{'//PurpleCar': [32L], '//BlackCar': [15L]}","{'EUR/JPY': [158L], 'ARS/MXN': [562L], 'GBP/JPY PAWS': [1759L]}"   
DEF,2016-6-12 0:00,0,"{'//PurpleCar': [28L], '//BlackCar': [96L]}","{'GBP/NOK OIS': [319], 'HKD/SAG': [103L], 'USD/INR': [3L]}"  
DEF,2016-6-13 0:00,0,"{'//PurpleCar': [32L], '//BlackCar': [15L]}","{'TNM6 2016-06-21': [193], 'EDH9': [1713L], 'GZ5': [0]}"
"""
```

As we can see from the first row of this new dataset, there are **TWO dictionaries** within double quotation marks and separated by a comma:

```
"{'//PurpleCar': [115L], '//YellowCar': [403L]}"
```

and

```
"{'GBP/NOK PAWS': [151L], 'CAD/EUR': [41L], 'EDM8-EDM9': [1833L]}"
```

(Whereas my original question posed in [How to remove curly braces, apostrophes and square brackets from dictionaries in a Pandas dataframe (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39928273/how-to-remove-curly-braces-apostrophes-and-square-brackets-from-dictionaries-in) dealt with only **ONE dictionary**.)

Also note that in this new data set, **the key values in the second dictionary can be basically anything**.

I use the following code to read in the data.  The first three columns are fixed and we leave them as they are. The fourth column (`"Cars_str"`) I parse with `ast.literal_eval` because it's a `dict`:

```
import ast
import pandas as pd

fixed_columns = pd.read_csv(StringIO(the_data),
                            names=["Company", "Date", "Value", "Cars_str",
                                   "Currency_str"])


cars = fixed_columns["Cars_str"].apply(ast.literal_eval)
del fixed_columns["Cars_str"]
```

Next, we prepare functions to process the keys and values of the `dict`:

```
def get_single_item(list_that_always_has_single_item):
    v, = list_that_always_has_single_item
    return v

def extract_car_name(car_str):
    assert car_str.startswith("//"), car_str
    return car_str[2:]
```

Then, we apply the functions and construct `pd.Series`:

```
dynamic_columns = cars.apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series({
            extract_car_name(k): get_single_item(v) 
            for k, v in x.items()
    }))
```

Finally, we add the columns to the data frame:

```
result = pd.concat([fixed_columns, dynamic_columns], axis=1)
result
```

Which gives us the following:

```
    Company Date    Value   Currency_str                                        BlackCar    PurpleCar   YellowCar
0   ABC 2016-6-9 0:00   95  {'GBP/NOK PAWS': [151L], 'CAD/EUR': [41L], 'ED...   NaN         115.0       403.0
1   ABC 2016-6-10 0:00  0   {'FBTPM5 2015-06-08': [472L], 'HKD/MXN': [0L],...   NaN         219.0       381.0
2   ABC 2016-6-11 0:00  0   {'V 2.000 03/31/25': [759L], 'AUD/JPY': [742L]...   NaN         572.0       184.0
3   ABC 2016-6-12 0:00  0   {'CAR/FIN SWAP': [151L], 'HKD/MXN': [41L], 'RU...   NaN         80.0        2011.0
4   ABC 2016-6-13 0:00  0   {'TRY/CHY OIS': [673L], 'NZD/MXN': [582L], 'AU...   NaN         32.0        15.0
5   DEF 2016-6-9 0:00   0   {'ULM5-ULU5 2015-06-19': [18L], 'HKD/MXN': [64...   17.0        19.0        NaN
6   DEF 2016-6-10 0:00  0   {'U 4.500 2/15/14': [151L], 'FVU6-FVZ6 2016-09...   15.0        32.0        NaN
7   DEF 2016-6-11 0:00  0   {'EUR/JPY': [158L], 'ARS/MXN': [562L], 'GBP/JP...   15.0        32.0        NaN
8   DEF 2016-6-12 0:00  0   {'GBP/NOK OIS': [319], 'HKD/SAG': [103L], 'USD...   96.0        28.0        NaN
9   DEF 2016-6-13 0:00  0   {'TNM6 2016-06-21': [193], 'EDH9': [1713L], 'G...   15.0        32.0        NaN
```

The problem I'm having is that I'd like to be able to take the `'Currency_str'` column and do the following:

1) extract the keys and set them as column headers in the data frame

2) keep the associated values of those keys as elements of the rows

This is **exactly** the same as we did for the `'Cars_str'` dictionary (and the solution I accepted in [How to remove curly braces, apostrophes and square brackets from dictionaries in a Pandas dataframe (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39928273/how-to-remove-curly-braces-apostrophes-and-square-brackets-from-dictionaries-in)).

Essentially, I'd like to be able to apply my above code to **both dictionaries**, where the keys are the column headers and the values are the elements of the rows.

Can anyone help me to amend the code such that we can accomplish points 1 and 2 above?

Thanks!

**UPDATE -->> THE SOLUTION:**

I found a solution that works.  Here it is:

```
import ast
import pandas as pd

fixed_columns = pd.read_csv(StringIO(the_data),
                            names=["Company", "Date", "Value", "Cars_str",
                                       "Currency_str"])


cars = fixed_columns["Cars_str"].apply(ast.literal_eval)
del fixed_columns["Cars_str"]

currencies = fixed_columns["Currency_str"].apply(ast.literal_eval)
del fixed_columns["Currency_str"]

def get_single_item(list_that_always_has_single_item):
    v, = list_that_always_has_single_item
    return v

def extract_car_name(car_str):
    assert car_str.startswith("//"), car_str
    return car_str[2:]

def extract_instrument_name(currency_str):
    assert currency_str.startswith(""), currency_str
    return currency_str[2:]


dynamic_column_01 = cars.apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series({
            extract_car_name(k): get_single_item(v) 
            for k, v in x.items()
    }))

dynamic_column_02 = currencies.apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series({
            extract_instrument_name(k): get_single_item(v) 
            for k, v in x.items()
    }))


result = pd.concat([fixed_columns, dynamic_column_01, dynamic_column_02], axis=1)
result
```

Comment: You could also just flatten the dictionaries before constructing the pandas DataFrame, so that each record is a simple non-nested dict. That would be about 5 lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
import ast
import pandas as pd

fixed_columns = pd.read_csv(StringIO(the_data),
                            names=["Company", "Date", "Value", "Cars_str",
                                       "Currency_str"])


cars = fixed_columns["Cars_str"].apply(ast.literal_eval)
del fixed_columns["Cars_str"]

currencies = fixed_columns["Currency_str"].apply(ast.literal_eval)
del fixed_columns["Currency_str"]

def get_single_item(list_that_always_has_single_item):
    v, = list_that_always_has_single_item
    return v

def extract_car_name(car_str):
    assert car_str.startswith("//"), car_str
    return car_str[2:]

def extract_instrument_name(currency_str):
    assert currency_str.startswith(""), currency_str
    return currency_str[2:]


dynamic_column_01 = cars.apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series({
            extract_car_name(k): get_single_item(v) 
            for k, v in x.items()
    }))

dynamic_column_02 = currencies.apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series({
            extract_instrument_name(k): get_single_item(v) 
            for k, v in x.items()
    }))


result = pd.concat([fixed_columns, dynamic_column_01, dynamic_column_02], axis=1)
result
```